# Is it possible to merge different video formats in one on a headless Linux server?

Tags: linux, video

I’ve different video formats (mostly `.mkv`, but also `.wmv` and `.mp4`). Is it possible to join these different formats in one video using the command line?

I'm using a headless server powered by Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Comment: Transcoding might not be necessary if the actual codecs are identical; most .mkv and .mp4 files use the same H.264 video. Either way, `ffmpeg` _should_ be able to handle it, although I don't know exactly how. (Only tried with MPEG2-TS, which supports it natively...)

Comment: What about  vlc? wasn't it able to save the stream to a file... something like `--sout `... [[1](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html#idp6249200),,[2](https://www.videolan.org/doc/videolan-howto/en/ch09.html)]. Ok maybe with some gym on the command line more... but it should be possible to set the output inside the GUI too.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -i video1.mov -i video2.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 output.mp4`

If you have more files you'll need to map them in the `filter_complex` argument section (i.e. ...[2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] etc.)

From the docs:

> n=2 is telling the filter that there are two input files; v=1 is
>   telling it that there will be one video stream; a=1 is telling it that
>   there will be one audio stream. [v] and [a] are names for the output
>   streams to allow the rest of the ffmpeg line to use the output of the
>   concat filter.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If the used codec is different, the step will also include transcoding. If it is the same, then the content is just copied over. A detailed guide can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.